# SQL group table values

Tags: mysql

So I have an SQL query which consists of a select, multiple subquerys, multiple joins and some where conditions. It looks something like:

```
SELECT concat(t1.name, ' ', t1.surname) AS users,
(SELECT t3.value AS col1 WHERE t6.id=343),
(SELECT t3.value AS col2 WHERE t6.id=344),
(SELECT t3.value AS col3 WHERE t6.id=345),
(SELECT t3.value AS col4 WHERE t6.id=346),
(SELECT t3.value AS col5 WHERE t6.id=347),
(SELECT t3.value AS col6 WHERE t6.id=348),
(SELECT t3.value AS col7 WHERE t6.id=349),
(SELECT t3.value AS col8 WHERE t6.id=350),
(SELECT t3.value AS col9 WHERE t6.id=351)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.id_table1_user=t1.id
JOIN table3 t3
ON t2.id=t3.id_eva
JOIN table4 t4
ON t3.id_pro_q=t4.id
JOIN table5 t5
ON t4.id_pro=t5.id
JOIN table6 t6
ON t4.id_t6=t6.id
JOIN table7 t7
ON t7.id_table1_user=t1.id
WHERE t5.id=151
```

It gives me this table:

[image: table 1]

Now... my question is - how can I group the rows so that there are only 2 rows and no NULLs? Is there a way?

Just to note - I am a total SQL beginner, so any suggestions on improving the command or anything are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a group by clause :

```
SELECT concat(t1.name, ' ', t1.surname) AS users,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 343 then t3.value end) as col1,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 344 then t3.value end) as col2,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 345 then t3.value end) as col3,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 346 then t3.value end) as col4,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 347 then t3.value end) as col5,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 348 then t3.value end) as col6,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 349 then t3.value end) as col7,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 350 then t3.value end) as col8,
       max (CASE WHEN t6.id = 351 then t3.value end) as col9
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id_table1_user = t1.id
  JOIN table3 t3
    ON t2.id = t3.id_eva
  JOIN table4 t4
    ON t3.id_pro_q = t4.id
  JOIN table5 t5
    ON t4.id_pro = t5.id
  JOIN table6 t6
    ON t4.id_t6 = t6.id
  JOIN table7 t7
    ON t7.id_table1_user = t1.id
 WHERE t5.id = 151
 GROUP BY concat(t1.name, ' ', t1.surname)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... tried that, unfortunately, and gives me an error:
ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "t3._value" from outer query

Comment: just tried with the concat... same error (see my last post)

Comment: @Pabos I changed all the subquries, so its not possible to get the same error! Recopy the code(Used case instead of subquery) and tell me if you get an error, what error is it

Comment: it works... you sir are brilliant! Thank you so much... could you please provide a little bit of insight as to why this works and my code didn't? Thank you again...

Comment: @Pabos No problem, And yes, thats because you cant group by a sub query in the select, unless you specify it in the group by clause too. Try to avoid this sub queries if not necessary , use CASE EXPRESSION like my solution in the future, will save you some trouble on this situations